# How to output white png version of my image ?**

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

With ImageMagick shell command (`convert`?)...

Given a colorful `input.png` image.

**How to us `input.png` to produce a white `output.jpg` version with similar dimensions an opacity of 100% ?**

I will later on use this layer in my workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `fill`, like this:

```
convert input.png -fill "#ffffff" output.jpg
```

or

```
convert input.png -fill white output.jpg
```

Or you can convert all three channels (red, green and blue) to "1" which is full intensity, like this:

```
convert input.png -channel red -fx "1" -channel green -fx "1" -channel blue -fx "1" output.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
convert input.png -threshold -1 output.jpg
```

This transforms any pixel with an intensity greater than (-1), i.e., all of them, to white.
It does not work with GraphicsMagick, though, because in GM the threshold value is unsigned (in ImageMagick it's a signed "double").  Neither of the applications documents exactly what is supposed to happen when the threshold is negative.

Here's a command that works on both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick, and is documented:

```
[gm] convert input.png -fuzz 100% -fill white -opaque gray output.jpg
```